# How to change the label in ui-grid footer

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

Using the ui-grid, how can I change the label for the aggregationType in the footer? Instead of the label saying Min or Max, I want to insert my own label. Is this possible?

```
aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.min
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an 'undocumented' (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef) property that can be used for this purpose : `aggregationLabel`